# How to change the styles (.sty) path in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, packages, paths, mac

I am using LyX Version 2.1.3 (for Mac Yosemite)

Library directory: `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/`

User directory: `~/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.1/`

If I go to Tools-> TeX information -> LaTeX styles:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/UKenglish.sty
...
/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/ae.sty
...
```

But I want to point to styles in:

```
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/
```

Comment: What TeX system is on your path (for example, the result of `command -v pdflatex` at the Terminal)? It looks like you have BasicTeX installed inside `/usr/local`, so I'm wondering why you want to point to `/opt/local/share`.

Comment: `$ command -v pdflatex` gives `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex`. I just want to tell Lyx that styles are in another dir.

Comment: @alemol if your TeX installation can find them, then so can LyX. The only think you need to do in LyX after you make your TeX installation aware of the files is to do Tools > Reconfigure

Comment: Tools > Reconfigure:  does not work